# parsing and analysing code coverage XML

Tags: c#, xml, sql-server-2008, xml-parsing, code-coverage

I have performed some unit tests and have obtained the code coverage XML from visual studio.Now I need to store those details in the SQL database I have designed. What is the best method to parse this XML and get the details I require.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use two ways depending upon what information you need and your requirements. The best way would depend upon your use case

1) You can create an XSLT to parse this XML and get the information that you need and store them in a database. That would be simple and quick.

2) If you wish to create the database and do additional handling, you can write a small helper in C# that parses this XML and stores the information in your database.